# iOS strong password autofill takes wrong field for username

Tags: ios, swift, authorization, uitextfield, autofill

I'm trying to introduce autofill into the register `ViewController` of my iOS app.
See below the layout of it. The textfields are subclasses of `UITextField`, the content type is set (from top to bottom) to `.name`, `.username`, `nil` and `.newPassword`. I've set up everything such that iOS suggests a strong password in the password field. When I press on register, iOS saves the password but it takes the value from the birthday field as username instead of the email address in the username field, which is very annoying.

Is the only way to fix this issue to change the fields email-address and birthday? Or did anybody find another way to fix this issue?

[image: Login Screen]

Comment: I'm running into the same issue, except my fields are [username, email address, password]. It looks like iOS is just taking whichever field is immediately above the password as the username and ignoring the `textContentType`.

Comment: I'm seeing this too, did you manage to solve?

Comment: I could just solve it with rearranging the fields...